# При выборе из базы получаю пустой массив

Tags: php

controller

```
$error_sms = $this->model_account_alphasms->getSms();

        print_r($error_sms);
```

получаю массив

```
Array ( [0] => 206 [1] => 206 )
```

передаю его в model

```
$this->model_account_order->getErrorMassage($error_sms);
```

model

```
  public function getErrorMassage($error_sms){

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($error_sms); $i++) {
        $number = $error_sms[$i];

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "sms_error WHERE number = '" . $number . "'")->rows;

        print_r($query); // получаю пустой массив
    }
}
```

если посмотреть

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "sms_error WHERE number = '" . $number . "'") print_r($query);

SELECT * FROM oc_sms_error WHERE number = '206'
SELECT * FROM oc_sms_error WHERE number = '206'
```

Comment: видимо в таблице oc_sms_error нет записи у которой number = '206'

Comment: Ну и откройте для себя `foreach`

Comment: @rjhdby Почему нужно делать через  `foreach` почему нельзя сделать через `for`

Comment: Не знаю но почему то у меня проблема в `$number` когда подставляешь просто число то все нормально, а когда `$number` то пустой массив, но `print_r($number)` 206 206

Comment: @Sender1050 как минимум это сократит код и улучшит читаемость, как максимум - foreach работает через интерфейс итератора. Да и count в каждой итерации будет жрать ресурсы

Comment: @rjhdby я переделал ` foreach($error_sms as $error){

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "sms_error WHERE number = '" . $error . "'");

            print_r($query->rows); // получаю пустой массив  
        }`  но в `$error` есть значения оно не пустой, может есть какой то способ увидеть ошибку , что не так

Comment: А поле `number` точно текстовое? Запрос без ошибок выполняется (на стороне БД)?

Comment: так записал в базу number varchar(100), если подставить вместо `$error`  число 206, то я получаю нужный ответ, `print_r($error)` мне отдает 206 206, что не так

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57688/discussion-between-sender1050-and-rjhdby).